# How should I use Regex with specified character?

Tags: regex

I am writing a code about inputting. Because the keyboard is customized, so the characters "/[]#*._" may appear but I forbid it!!
Actually I can write the code as below:

```
    if (!_UID.IndexOf(@"/").Equals(-1))
    {
        return ErrorMessage;
    }
    else if (!_UID.IndexOf(@"\").Equals(-1))
    {
        return ErrorMessage;
    }
    else if (!_UID.IndexOf(@"[").Equals(-1))
    {
        return ErrorMessage;
    }
    else if (!_UID.IndexOf(@"]").Equals(-1))
    {
        return ErrorMessage;
    }
    else if (!_UID.IndexOf(@"#").Equals(-1))
    {
        return ErrorMessage;
    }
    else if (!_UID.IndexOf(@"*").Equals(-1))
    {
        return ErrorMessage;
    }
    else if (!_UID.IndexOf(@".").Equals(-1))
    {
        return ErrorMessage;
    }
    else if (!_UID.IndexOf(@"_").Equals(-1))
    {
        return ErrorMessage;
    }
```

But it's so cheap!! It's clearly that I wanna to forbid those chars in the TextBox and I hope I can express the code with Regex, how should I coding this??

Answer (score 0):

You can make it easier by doing something like this

```
foreach(char c in "/[]#*._"){
   if(!_UID.IndexOf(c.ToString()) == -1) return ErrorMessage;
}
```

But if you really want regex, you could do

```
if(!Regex.IsMatch(_UID, "[/[]#*._]")){
   return ErrorMessage;
}
```

Comment: So sorry about Regex, it's not correct....
I've tried the input such as "A123456789" and "A.12345678", the result are the same. In this case, "." is forbidden~

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if(!Regex.IsMatch(_UID, "[/[]#*._]")){
>    return ErrorMessage;
> }
> ```

This is wrong in two aspects:

- It's an error if there is a forbidden character matched, so the `!` is out of place; correct:
  `if (Regex.IsMatch(…)) return ErrorMessage;`
- `[/[]#*._]` is **not** a character class with the set of characters `/` `[` `]` `#` `*` `.` `_`, because the first `]` ends the character class `[/[]`, which is then followed by `#*` `.` `_` `]`; this would match something like `"…[###x_]…"`, not what is desired. To include `]` in a character class, it can be placed right after the opening bracket. Correct:
  `if (Regex.IsMatch(_UID, "[]/[#*._]")) return ErrorMessage;`